# Bluetooth command to turn off in the Bios

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, ms-dos

I'm trying figure out how to turn off Bluetooth in the bios using a DOc command. Is that possible? I know you can get the computer serial number doing that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Each BIOS interface is proprietary. There is no built in method in the operating system to configure BIOS settings.

However, if the manufacturer provides a method to change BIOS settings you may be able to use whatever method they have provided.

Some higher end systems have this capability. Such as Dell Latitude systems using Dell Command & Configure.

Your ability to do so, or not, will be entirely dependent on the capabilities the manufacturer has provided for you.